# How do I filter by subtitle and title instead just one?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuejs2

Currently I am using computed property for displaying data on my website and I am returning the array from it:

```
filteredPackages: function () {
  let titleSearch = this.packages.filter((mypackage, index, arr) => {
    return mypackage.title.match(new RegExp(this.search, "i")) 
  });
  return titleSearch; 
}
```

Currently, it is only searching the search string in the `title` property only, but I want to implement it in such a way that it will search the `title` as well as `sub_title`.

```
filteredPackages: function () {
  let titleSearch = this.packages.filter((mypackage, index, arr) => {
    return mypackage.title.match(new RegExp(this.search, "i")) 
  });

  let subTitleSearch = this.packages.filter((mypackage, index, arr) => {
    return mypackage.sub_title.match(new RegExp(this.search, "i")) 
  });
  return subTitleSearch;
}
```

But now it is only searching in one array of subtitles. How can I search it in title as well as subtitle and then return the array from my computed property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check both the subtitle and title in one predicate by using `Array#some`:

```
let titleSearch = this.packages.filter(({ title, sub_title }) =>
  [title, sub_title].some(prop => prop.match(new RegExp(this.search, "i")))
);
```

What this does is take the `title` and `sub_title` properties and put them in array. If *either the subtitle or title match the regular expression*, then the item is kept.

Comment: its a brilliant approach. Thank you very much for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are returning the second array only. Simply use array `concat` method

```
return titleSearch.concat(subTitleSearch)
```

Or, if you want to avoid duplicate entries, you can do the following

```
subTitleSearch = subTitleSearch.filter( s => titleSearch.indexOf(s) == -1);
return titleSearch.concat(subTitleSearch);
```

Comment: Edited the answer to remove duplicate values